# Preserve TableCell BackColor seted on client side on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, custom-controls

What is the best way to save BackColor of asp:Tabel **TableCell** set on client side by javascript on posback ?

What property do I override while creating custom control based on Table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to respond myself to that.
**TableCell** would have to implement input controls capabilities , because only those controls can pass their values back to server.

I ended up with using check box control that is hidden in every cell to preserve the state ( cell colored , not colored) and jQuery to help me with css and checking appropriate boxes.